# Can we say that processes (with or without subprocesses) are totally reflected in their (descriptive) files?

Tags: process, file-descriptors

Can we say that a whole "series" of files in a process (as represented respectively by file descriptors) directly reflect this process and possible sub processes of it, so that taking a respective look at the files, described by the file descriptors, could tell us the exact nature of the process and possible subprocesses?

In other words, if you look at **each file** (represented by file descriptors in a respective order like 0-X), will it tell you the nature of the process or/and subprocesses?

I believe the answer would be yes, if indeed, the whole process is really made out only of these files.

Comment: Are you asking if one can write a statically linked program that closes all of its file descriptors and continues to run?

Comment: Hmm, it's not what I'm asking.

Comment: OK.  So, if I wrote such a program that had few, if any, open descriptors, what would you expect to glean from it?  That is, if you ran an `lsof(8)` on it and found no open descriptors, then what?

Put another way, if I wrote a program that opened every library on the system just for fun, what would you expect to learn from the list of open descriptors?

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult (much), but it's not clear to me that which files are open tells you anything other than "this process has these files open".

I find the question interesting, but am I missing the point?
(Sorry for the two part comment.  It timed out.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No

Long answer: The file descriptors used by a process aren't static enough to allow a reliable analysis of the process. Files can be opened and closed, the corresponding data structures will be recycled by the kernel.

Comment: Thanks Eugen. Can you please try to clarify in parenthesis the saying: "the corresponding data structures will be recycled by the kernel."?

Comment: Oh, and, if you take a look at the files of the file descriptors in a respective order (0-X), I believe this is indeed reliable for analysis.

Comment: @Benia: The point is, _fd numbers_ are also recycled. If you have 10 files open, and you call close(4), then the 11th file (if you ever open it in the future) will get fd #4 again, and the original file will no longer be reflected anywhere at all.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: Write two programs that both sleep for, say, 100 seconds, and then write 1 resp. 2 to stderr. Start both from the same shell and put them in the background. You won't be able to distinguish them by looking at the file descriptors, which are identical for both.

Variant: Have them open the same file, so it doesn't even work if it's not restricted to the to the standard descriptors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I fully understand what you are asking... Please add some explanation.

But from what I think I understand, **No**.

An analogy could be:

> If I watch Person A and see who they talk to, can I determine the intent of Person A?

In this case, that answer is quite murky. You might be able to see that Person A talks to some important person in law enforcement, and perhaps some people associated with organised crime. But it is going to be extremely difficult (impossible?) to state for certain the motives of Person A. Are they an undercover cop, or a criminal with a judge under their thumb?

You can't reliably read anything into such knowledge alone.

If you managed to ascertain more information, such as the I/O that is being performed, then you would be on your way to understanding the situation more clearly.

---

> In other words, if you look at each file (represented by file descriptors in a respective order like 0-X), will it tell you the nature of the process and or subprocesses?

I think you are somewhat confused about what a '*file descriptor*' is. A file descriptor is identified by a simple number (`int`) - the return value of `open()`... but within the kernel a file descriptor has information associated with it. See [`struct file`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L835).

---

> I believe the answer would be yes, if indeed, the whole process is really made out only of these files.

This also holds some evidence of mis-understanding. A process is not "*made out of only these files*", but instead is accessing these files *right now*. We can show this by running the following:

```bsh
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 attie attie 64 May 20 15:20 0 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 attie attie 64 May 20 15:20 1 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 attie attie 64 May 20 15:20 2 -> /dev/pts/3
lr-x------ 1 attie attie 64 May 20 15:20 3 -> /proc/13103/fd
```

As @grawity has pointed out in a comment, `open()` will return the next free file descriptor, filling any gaps from zero. What you see above is a snapshot of files that are currently open, and will change over time.

---

You can't see the `ls` binary in the above list, or any of its immediate dependencies:

```bsh
$ ldd $(which ls)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff569ef000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007feeb33df000)
        libacl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007feeb31d7000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007feeb2e0e000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007feeb2bd0000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007feeb29cc000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007feeb361a000)
        libattr.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1 (0x00007feeb27c6000)
```

When you try to "*execute `ls`*" the linker is actually what reads the library files to collate and 'link' the full process image. By the time `ls` starts to execute, this data is already in memory and the files are not 'open' anymore.

Some applications may make use of 'plugins', or 'dynamically' load additional files that provide functionality (see [`dlopen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen)), but this is an edge case and is far from typical behaviour - none of the processes currently running on my machine have a Shared Object (`*.so`) file open.

---

In summary, and still in agreement with my original answer, **No**.

There is no definitive way to determine the behaviour of a process by looking at what files it has open.

As far as determining the nature of a subprocess, this is impossible - can you look at `init` and determine the full runtime configuration of a system? **No**.

Comment: Hello Attie, to make sure you understand me correctly, I tried to edit my question. If any further clarification needed - I'd be glad to add it. Have we been on the same direction with this?

Comment: @Benia I've updated my answer to add details, and hopefully address some apparent mis-understandings

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, but in a very limited way.

In fact, watching what a process does is one of the main functions of an
antivirus, as among the files that are opened are also those of DLLs (Windows)
or shared libraries (Linux).
An antivirus that judges the behavior of a process will raise the alarm
when a process opens too many or too sensitive files, or try to access
sensitive folders. Windows/Linux may ask for user permission in such cases.

It is possible to detect that a process is opening a DLL/shared-library,
but to find out which APIs it calls requires the analysis of the system
calls that it does, which an antivirus can find by examining the executable
file itself of the process.

Do not forget that the executable itself is one of the opened files,
so that its analysis can tell exactly which DLLs/shared-libraries it uses,
which can give a very good understanding of what it does.

The OS will watch the behavior of the process and will classify it in a
scheduling class as a CPU-bound or IO-bound or mixed, which will affect its
execution priority and its allowed slices of system resources.

A sub-process will usually inherit all the opened file-descriptors of its
parent, and therefore will start its life in the same classification
in the eyes of the OS and antivirus, but may later on, through its actions,
move to another classification.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Most processes have very similar descriptor behavior. For example, nearly all daemons write their output to logs (files), which are often shared. For example, on my system `/var/log/journal` has entries from `systemd`, `gnome-keyring-*`, `dbus-daemon` and many programs more.

One pattern which is often used is redirecting descriptors to/from `/dev/{null,zero,urandom,tty*}`, or closing them.

Another example - `cmp` and `diff` do basically the same, but they deal with different type of data.

There are even programs in [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package (which is brilliant) that wrap some common descriptor patterns:

- `chronic` - runs a command quietly unless it fails
- `sponge` - soak up standard input and write to a file (the file is opened *after* the input is soaked, so that `grep "mom" somefile | sponge somefile` leaves only those lines in somefile which contain "mom" )
- combine - combine sets of lines from two files using boolean operations (same descriptors as `diff`)

And imagine, how fast descriptors are changing for `top` or `find` programs.  You would need to trace them during their whole execution time.

A take-home question: what is the difference in descriptors between LibreOffice Writer and GIMP, or better, `sed` and WannaCry?